# popup window closing service

Tags: android, service, popupwindow, android-input-method

I am trying to show a `PopupWindow` within an `InputMethodService`, but when I show it using this code:

```
LayoutInflater inflater = ( LayoutInflater ) getSystemService( LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE );
pw = new PopupWindow(
inflater.inflate(R.layout.info_dialog, null, false), 320, 480, true);
pw.showAtLocation(mInputView, Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
```

the window will flash briefly before closing my `InputMethodService`.

The error I get from LogCat is just this:

```
12-21 15:22:20.530: E/InputMethodService(4075): Unexpected null in startExtractingText : mExtractedText = null, input connection = com.android.internal.view.InputConnectionWrapper@40a60150
```

Has anyone seen this before or know how to deal with it?

Answer (score 0):

Is there any **REAL** reason why you aren't using an AlertDialog/Dialog? Why based on your code, a dialog would suite this. It will popup right in the middle of the user's screen and you can populate the view that is there. And, you can even set listeners to it!

Comment: The REAL reason is in the first line of my question. I am in an InputMethodService. Dialogs cannot be used in services.

Comment: uh, yes they can. All you need is context. Unless, "InputMethodService" is some 'special' kind of service. Which I doubt. I'll look into it.

Comment: Well I was wrong, you can't do this directly, but you can send an intent from your service to your Activity to handle bringing up that Dialog, check my updated post.

Comment: Not if you don't have an Activity involved.

Comment: Then you should post this kind of information. We can't read your mind.